# Cannot convert value of type 'AppDelegate' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement google sign in on my app but when i add the `signIn()` function i'm getting this error below

```
Cannot convert value of type 'AppDelegate' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'
```

**My function:**

```
@IBAction func signIn(sender: Any) {
  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: self) { user, error in
    guard error == nil else { return }

    // If sign in succeeded, display the app's main content View.
  }
}
```

Comment: Which file is the signIn function in? The AppDelegate or a view controller?

Comment: is this really a SwiftUI question?

Comment: @strwils Is on my AppDelegate file

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen the signature for the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn` function, but the problem is likely `presenting: self`. That parameter probably must be a view controller, and you are passing in an `AppDelegate`. The easiest fix is to move that function into a view controller, or, pass a view controller that your `AppDelegate` has a reference to. That second option is more than I can explain in a short post here, but I'm sure there are other posts related to it.

Comment: can you explain how can i to move that function into a view controller, please?

Comment: That is very basic. Are you aware of what a view controller is and how to create one?

Comment: Yes, I'm beginner on iOS development

Comment: @strwils what if I have no view controllers in my app (SwiftUI 2.0)? And I'm using UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor for appDelegate, so it has no reference to a view controller. There's 0 information on the internet about this type of a problem.